# How can I define a filter function for arrows?

Tags: haskell, arrows

I'm currently reading through the paper [Programming with Arrows](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf) by John Hughes
and I'm already stumped on the first exercise, in section 2.5, on pg 20.

We have the `Arrow` and `ArrowChoice` typeclasses at our disposal, as well as instances for functions, stream functions `[a] -> [b]`, and monadic functions `a -> m b` via the `Kleisli` type.

A `mapA` example was given:

```
mapA f = arr listcase >>>
         arr (const []) ||| (f *** mapA >>> arr (uncurry (:)))
```

Here's an attempt:

```
listcase :: [a] -> (Either () (a,[a]))
listcase [] = Left ()
listcase (x:xs) = Right (x,xs)

helper :: (Bool,a) -> [a] -> Either (a,[a]) [a]
helper (True,x)  y = Left (x,y)
helper (False,x) y = Right y

test :: Arrow a => (b -> Bool) -> a (b,c) ((Bool,b), c)
test p = first (arr p &&& arr id)

filterA :: Arrow a => (b -> Bool) -> a [b] [c]
filterA p = f >>> (g ||| (h >>> (j ||| (filterA p))))
   where f = arr listcase
         g = arr (const [])
         h = test p >>> (uncurry helper)
         j = (arr id *** (filterA p)) >>> (arr (uncurry (:)))
```

The (bruteforce) rationale behind this futile attempt is as follows:
There are two choices to be made with `filterA`: the `listcase` like `map`, and the result of applying the predicate `p`.  It starts off like `map`, checking the list and returning an Either value using `listcase`.  In the case of an empty list `g` is applied, otherwise everything to the right of `|||` is applied to a value of type `(a,[a])`, containing the `head` and `tail` respectively.  The `h` function is applied first, which applies the predicate while keeping the `head`, returning a value of type `((Bool, head),tail)`.  This is passed to `(uncurry helper)`, which decides whether to keep the `head` or not depending on the `Bool` value.  It returns the result as an `Either` value so that we may apply the choice method `(|||)` to it.  This value is passed to the next choice: `(j ||| (filterA p))` such that if the predicate held `True` then `j` is applied to a pair containing the `head` and `tail`.  The `head` is filtered through using `id` while the `filter p` is applied to the `tail`.  Both results are returned as a pair.  This pair is then reconciled using `arr (uncurry (:))` like `map`.  Otherwise the `tail` is passed to `filterA p` alone.

I doubt it's as difficult as I'm making it out to be, I assume I'm missing something quite obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I'm not quite following your logic, but let's see **what the non-arrow code does**. It

- Checks to see if the list is empty, if so returns that
- Otherwise, pulls the head of the list off, call the element `x`
- Recurses on the rest of the list, call the result `ys`
- If the predicate `p` is true on the head, then we append `x` to `ys`.
- Otherwise, we return `ys`

The `listcase` function [to implement the first 2 tasks] looks good, though remember you're returning a list, so might as well return that instead of `unit` and remapping through `const []`.

You have the recursion code for the third bullet buried in the two last cases, whereas I expose it directly, but that's okay.

For the last merging, you write it with a `|||`, but since you don't need to compose any other arrows in your target category, you might as well just lift a function to do all of the work. In my code below, that's `rejoin`.

```
filterA :: forall arr a. ArrowChoice arr => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]
filterA p = arr lstcase >>> (filterRest ||| id) where
    -- left if has a head, right otherwise
    lstcase :: [a] -> (Either (a, [a]) [a])
    lstcase (x:xs) = Left (x, xs)
    lstcase [] = Right []

    -- if we got a head, then
    --     for the head ("first" in code), map this to itself and p's result on it
    --     recurse on the rest of the list ("second" part)
    --     append the element to the recursion result if p's result is true
    filterRest :: arr (a, [a]) [a]
    filterRest = (first (id &&& p) >>> second (filterA p) >>> arr rejoin)

    rejoin :: ((a, Bool), [a]) -> [a]
    rejoin ((x, True), rest) = x:rest
    rejoin ((x, False), rest) = rest
```

Certainly it takes time to express your ideas clearly with the likes of `***`, `&&&`, `|||`, `first`, etc.

A little critique.

- Make sure you're implementing the function they're asking for!! If you just take a raw function `p`, then you might as well declare `filterA = arr filter`. You really want to take a lifted arrow `p`. That said, the change would be to simply type `p` instead of `arr p`, so your code has the right idea.
- `(uncurry helper)` is not something in the arrow space, it's just a raw function.

When developing this stuff, I usually write a skeleton, and declare the types. That helps me figure out what's going on. For example, I started with

```
filterA :: ArrowChoice arr => arr a Bool -> arr [a] [a]
filterA p = arr lstcase >>> (filterRest ||| id) where
    -- left if has a head, right otherwise
    lstcase :: [a] -> (Either (a, [a]) [a])
    lstcase = undefined

    filterRest :: arr (a, [a]) [a]
    filterRest = undefined
```

When you add `fa` into the `filterRest` declaration however, you need to tell it that `arr` for `filterRest` is the same as the one for `filterA` (type variable scoping), so use the `forall arr a.` as above.

Comment: Thanks, looks good.  I had noticed that the predicate was an arrow right after I posted, but since it didn't change things much, as you pointed out, I didn't bother changing it. Not lifting `(uncurry helper)` was a mistake.  Perhaps the biggest mistake was not making `filterA p` an `ArrowChoice` instance.  That simple change allows my code to work as expected, although I prefer yours.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight simplification:

```
test :: Arrow a => (b -> Bool) -> a b ([b] -> [b])
test p = arr $ \b -> if p b then (b:) else id
         
filterA :: Arrow a => (b -> Bool) -> a [b] [b]
filterA p = f >>> (g ||| h)
  where f = arr listcase
        g = arr id
        h = (test p *** filterA p) >>> (arr (uncurry ($)))

filterA' :: Arrow a => a b Bool -> a [b] [b]
filterA' p = f >>> (g ||| h)
  where f = arr listcase
        g = arr id
        h = (i *** filterA p) >>> (arr (uncurry ($)))
        i = proc x -> do 
              b <- p -< x
              returnA -< if b then (x:) else id
```